# Unable to move Uploaded file with original name

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I am trying to store my image name in database and image in folder. Images are moving but the problem is images are not storing with original name. Some temp name(image) prefixing with my image name.

My code:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = 'image/image';
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * from image WHERE image_name = '$pic' ");

if(!$query1) {
    echo "error";
}

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query1);
if ($rows != 1) {
    //Writes the information to the database
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO image(image_name) VALUES ('$pic')");

    //Writes the photo to the server
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        //Tells you if its all ok
        echo "The file  has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
    }
    else {
        //Gives and error if its not
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
}
else {
    echo "image already exits in database";
}
```

How to solve this problem. Any clue ?

Comment: Try $target = 'image/image/';
I think you are missing a /

Comment: no facing error : move_uploaded_file(image/image/Error.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: @foxbeefly is right, you need to add a directory separator... On a side note, you should insert in your database only if the file_move succeeded, or else you'll see images that do not exist

Comment: $target = "/image/image/" try  with this

Answer (score 1):

Code you used:

```
//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = 'image/image';
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
```

If you use `'image/image'`, then the images will be stored under `image/` directory with prefix `image` and image_name i.e., `imageimage_name.jpg`

If you face any error when using `image/image/`, please check whether you are having directory structure like `'image/image/'` or only `image/`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$target= 'image/image'; 
$imagename = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$target = $target.$imagename;
$temp = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $target)) {
    echo "File is  successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    /* This is the directory where images will be saved */
    $target = 'image/image';
    /* Full target path for uploaded image */
    $target = $target . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'] );



    /* This gets all the other information from the form */
    $pic=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $query1 = mysql_query( "SELECT * from `image` WHERE `image_name` = '$pic';" );



    if( !$query1 ) {

        echo "error querying database";

    } else {

        $rows = mysql_num_rows( $query1 );

        /* If there are no records in db for this piture, add a record */
        if ( $rows == 0 ) {

            /* Writes the information to the database */
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `image` (`image_name`) VALUES ('$pic');");

            /* Writes the photo to the server */
            if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target ) ) {

                /* Tells you if its all ok */
                echo "The file  has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";

            } else {

                /* Gives and error if its not */
                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";

            }
        } else {
            echo "image already exits in database";
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $_FILES['fileup']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'];
$target_dir = "uploads/".basename($file);
if($file!="") {
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$target_dir)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'not success';
    }
}
```